# how to optimize bash command with nested sub-command?

Tags: bash, shell, optimization, autocomplete

current code do work, is there any way to optimize it?
seems jq cmd cost lots of time to work result out of json struct.
which make autocomplete quite slow.

the code below try to define a nested shell command struct with json text, then use jq command to parse the json text, and parse autocomplete results.

```sh
function _auto_completion_linux_ext() {
    COMPREPLY=()

    local cmd="${COMP_WORDS[1]}"
    local cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    local prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    local opts
#    printf "\n[COMP_WORDS] -> ${COMP_WORDS}\n"
#    printf "\n[COMP_CWORD] -> ${COMP_CWORD} -> ${cur}\n"

    read -r -d '' var_basic_json << EOV
{
  "init": {
    "hostname": {}
  },
  "firewall": {
    "enable": {},
    "disable": {},
    "reload": {},
    "add": {
      "tcp": {},
      "udp": {}
    },
    "del": {
      "tcp": {},
      "udp": {}
    },
    "list": {}
  },
  "network": {
    "ipv4": {
      "dhcp": {},
      "static": {}
    },
    "ipv6": {
      "dhcp": {},
      "static": {}
    }
  },
  "status": {
    "tcp": {},
    "listening_port": {}
  },
  "upgrade": {}
}
EOV

    case ${COMP_CWORD} in
        1):
          opts=$(echo ${var_basic_json} | jq -j ". | keys | join(\" \")")
        ;;
        *):
          local var_jq_idx=()
          local var_jq_idx_str
          for ((i = 1; i <= COMP_CWORD; i++)); do
            var_jq_idx_str=$(echo ${var_jq_idx[@]} | tr " " ".")
            if [[ $(echo ${var_basic_json} | jq -j ".${var_jq_idx} | has(\"${COMP_WORDS[i]}\")") ]]; then
              var_jq_idx+=(${COMP_WORDS[i]})
            else
              break
            fi
          done

          opts=$(echo ${var_basic_json} | jq -j ".${var_jq_idx_str} | keys | join(\" \")")
        ;;
    esac

    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}))
    return 0;
}

complete -F _auto_completion_linux_ext system
```

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Always quote your variables unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: If performance is important, don't use shell scripts in the first place, use a real programming language.

Comment: Try with Python, for example ;) . Launching a new process for almost every line is generally not great for performance in pathological cases.